# Unwanted movement after UIImage Collision

Tags: iphone, xcode, timer, uiimage, collision

Ok this is my first post, and I am still VERY new at Xcode and Objective C. Iv'e been self teaching myself for the past few weeks. Anyways, Im practicing by making a small game where you control a helicopter and collect coins that drop. I have been having some trouble with the object collision method though. The biggest problem is that after successful collision the Helicopter will automatically be moved back to its starting location, which I do not want. I want the Helicopter UIImage to stay in its new location. I have checked every line of my code and no where do I call to recreate the Helicopter.frame in its original position.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *UserMoveTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pos = [UserMoveTouch locationInView: self.view];
    if(pos.x<356)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"CopterMoveTo" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: .5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

        CopterPlayer.center = [UserMoveTouch locationInView:self.view];

        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}


-(void)CopterCollisionCheck
{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(Coin1.frame, CopterPlayer.frame))
    {
        SystemSoundID soundID;
        NSString *CoinSound=[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             pathForResource:@"GetCoin" ofType:@"wav"];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)
                                         [NSURL fileURLWithPath:CoinSound], & soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        Coin1.frame=CGRectMake(Coin1.center.x+150,15,20,23);
        if (MultiplierX==1)
        {
            ScoreValue=ScoreValue+1;
        }
        else if(MultiplierX==2)
        {
            ScoreValue=ScoreValue+2;
        }
        else if(MultiplierX==3)
        {
            ScoreValue=ScoreValue+3;
        {
    }
    ScoreValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ScoreValue];


}


-(void)CopterCollisionTimer
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.35 target:self            
    selector:@selector(CopterCollisionCheck) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I apologize if I forgot a bracket or something with the pasting of the code, not use to formatting posts on this site. Remember first noobie post! Help greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

pshhh this goes to show how noobish I am...Didn't realize constantly changing a label text value during gameplay would make UIImages freak out. Changed it to a textfield and all is well :)